# PGSQL Loop throught table

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to Postgresql and I'm struggling on a Loop. I tried to understand other post about this subject but i'm still stuck.

I have a table "Alltrips" with GPS positions (X,Y) and timestamp, from different tracks (column trips). Each track have an ID. What i want to do is perform an action on each set of track.

I would like to update `doublon_timestamp` column to becomes `True` if the next line has the same timestamp. But the line must not be True if the last timestamp of a track has the same timestamp as the first line of the next track.

I would like to proceed in this way because I intend to reuse this procedure to draw lines between GPS points of each tracks but not  link the last point of a track with the first of the next track.

I tried something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.testloop(
) RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
x alltrips.trips_id;
BEGIN
    FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM public.alltrips)
LOOP
    CASE WHEN alltrips.timedate = lead(alltrips.timedate) 
              OVER (ORDER BY alltrips.trips_id) 
            THEN UPDATE public.alltrips SET doublon_timestamp = true;
        END CASE;
END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$;
```

But isn't working. I know that I have a trouble in my `DECLARE` section.
What is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your requirement can be achieved with a single `UPDATE FROM` statement with a derived table rather than going for a function and unnecessary loops.

You could try something like this (untested)

```
UPDATE alltrips t 
SET    doublon_timestamp = d.doublon_timestamp 
FROM   (SELECT trips_id, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN timedate = LEAD(timedate) 
                                   OVER ( 
                                     ORDER BY trips_id) THEN true 
               END AS doublon_timestamp from alltrips) d 
WHERE  d.trips_id = t.trips_id;
```

Although you seem to suggest there are other criteria to check before updating, it is hard to provide you  a working solution unless you provide some *sample data* in the question, which is *clearly missing.*

Comment: You're updating all rows of the table here, not just the "duplicate" ones.

Comment: @Ancoron : you may be right. But, I'll correct it only to suit the OP's expected output and data if they wish to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `trips_id` is an index per track `trips`, for which I came up with the following example table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE alltrips (
    trips integer,
    trips_id integer not null,
    timedate timestamptz not null,
    doublon_timestamp boolean not null default false,
    primary key (trips, trips_id)
);
```

Based on this, there is no need for a function as already pointed out:

```sql
UPDATE alltrips AS u
SET doublon_timestamp = true
FROM (
    SELECT trips, trips_id, timedate, lead(timedate) OVER (ORDER BY trips, trips_id) AS next
    FROM alltrips
    ORDER BY 1, 2
) AS t
WHERE
    t.trips = u.trips
    AND
    t.trips_id = u.trips_id
    AND
    t.timedate = t.next
;
```

Online example with data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/925f5/1/0

At least with the structure in place that I've used, the execution plan is really neat:

```
                                                QUERY PLAN                                                 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on alltrips u  (cost=0.30..114.66 rows=1 width=63)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.30..114.66 rows=1 width=63)
         ->  Subquery Scan on t  (cost=0.15..99.60 rows=9 width=48)
               Filter: (t.timedate = t.next)
               ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.15..76.98 rows=1810 width=24)
                     ->  Index Scan using alltrips_pkey on alltrips  (cost=0.15..45.30 rows=1810 width=16)
         ->  Index Scan using alltrips_pkey on alltrips u  (cost=0.15..1.67 rows=1 width=22)
               Index Cond: ((trips = t.trips) AND (trips_id = t.trips_id))
(8 rows)
```

No sorts and merge joins always is a good sign... ;)